# Why did this PIC circuit short circuit?

Tags: voltage, analog, voltage-regulator, pic, short-circuit

I have short circuit problem in an analog reader circuit with a PIC 18F4620.

There is a potentiometer connected to pin AN0. The resistance value of the potentiometer is shown on a 7 segment display (common anode.) I used an LM317 to regulate the input voltage.

An adaptor is used to decrease 220 V AC to 12 V DC and the LM317 is used to decrease 12 V to 5 V 1 A.  It measures 5.053 V to be exact. The resistors used for the LM317 circuit are 1 kΩ and 330 Ω.

Schematic:

[image]

PCB:

[image]

Back side of the PCB:

[image]

Front side of the PCB, right before it stopped working:

[image]

Here's what happened:

When I plugged in the adaptor, there was only one digit working on the 7 segment display. When I moved the 5-pin-header around, the circuit started to work normally. (I used jumper cables to solder the header in place because I used the wrong package while drawing the PCB. It was too narrow for the pins.)

Then I decided to wait for a while to see what happens if the circuit stays powered up for some time.

After 5 - 7 minutes, smoke came from behind the PCB and the circuit stopped working. I thought maybe the LM317 burned so I replaced it with a new one, but when I plugged the adaptor in again, one digit lit up and after 1 or 2 seconds it stopped working again.

I checked the circuit with a multimeter, the results are like this:

1. Every possible + and - pin of everything is short circuited, including the PIC, capacitors (other than the ones that are connected to the crystal,) potentiometer, etc.
2. The resistors used for the LM317 circuit have different values. 330 Ω became 250 Ω, 1 kΩ became 270 Ω.

3-l. There isn't any problem with other resistors in the circuit and capacitors that are connected to crystal.

Then I unsoldered pins 29 and 28. (GND and VDD pins.)  That solved the short circuit, but the LM317 resistors still do not have correct values. This time 1 kΩ became 470 Ω and 330 Ω became 270 Ω. Now I'm afraid to plug the circuit in because I don't want to damage the PIC.

What could have caused the short circuit in the first place? Do you think the PIC was damaged when it got short circuited?

Comment: Please upload a schematic with componet values. Where did the smoke come from?

Comment: @Justme I am not really sure where the smoke came from but LM317 was too hot and the PIC was just a little warm. So I think one of them was the source of the smoke.

Comment: What’s your 5 V DC load current?

Comment: @winny It's 1A.

Comment: When you measure things in-circuit you are not only measuring that component but also everything connected to it in parallel.

Comment: "Every possible + and - pin of everything is short circuited. Including The PIC, capacitors (other than the ones that are connected to the crystal), potentiometer etc." It will be shorted until you can remove the component that is shorting the whole rail

Comment: `Then I unsoldered 29. and 28. pins. (GND and VDD pins): The short circuit problems solved.` are you sure? 29-28 are shorted to 6-7 through both the PCB and the chip (internally). So if the chip's VDD-VSS pair is the problem then the short circuit problems cannot disappear by desoldering 29-28 pair only.

Comment: When you say something is "shorted", are you referring to a "continuity test" on your meter, or an actual near Zero Ohms ohmmeter reading?  The continuity buzzer will sound for any low resistance value - perhaps anything below 50 - 100 Ohms.

Comment: (12-5 V) * 1 A = 7 W of losses in your LM317. This will overheat quickly.

Comment: There's no base resistors, and the NPN transistors are used on high side of load as emitter followers. You usually don't do that. I can't guarantee that is the reason it started smoking though.

Comment: Why are there scrape marks coming from between the IC pins? If it was to try to clear solder bridges, the better method would have been to use a soldering iron to remove the bridges, or a bit of desoldering braid. If there were bridges around there, maybe there are more bridges elsewhere that might be found by examining the board with a magnifying glass (although it doesn't look like any other pads are that close together).

Comment: @Justme, there are resistors on the emitters, after the LEDs in the display.

Comment: In addition to @Justme's comment: If you switch the high side of a load, you certainly want to use PNP transistors. And you want to use series resistors at each transistor's base to limit its current. This hint is quite simplified, but correct for your application.

Comment: @OskarSkog  Yes there are. But I don't mean those resistors.

Comment: I mean, it should work fine to use emitter followers to drive LEDs with 5V logic (4.3 V remaining). And as long as the transistors are wired correctly it can't be the cause for the short. @Justme Shouldn't the base current be limited by the emitter resistance and gain of the transistor?